# What free mindmapping software will allow interactive mindmaps to be published?

Tags: gratis, mind-mapping

I'd like to create a mindmap of **textboxes** connected by branches.

I'd like some of these textboxes to be '**collapsible**', i.e. there is some sort of **interactive** element/ button that I can press to expand a textbox, to show more text.

I'd then like to publish this mindmap so it is accessible to other users (online or offline, it doesn't matter), but with the interactive elements **remaining** interactive to those other users.

Can anyone recommend a **free** software that can meet these requirements? It could be online or offline, but should be able to run on Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

> [MindMup](http://blog.mindmup.com/p/documentation.html) is a free, opensource, online mindmapping canvas. It is:
>
> - Zero friction: Access your data anywhere, from any device. Use our free cloud storage for public mindmaps. Store private mind maps on
>     Google Drive, with detailed access and sharing control. All this
>     without the need to register, have accounts or remember passwords.
> - Productive: User interface automatically adjusts to touch displays or desktops/laptops systems. On desktops, all map operations
>     have keyboard shortcuts. On mobile devices, toolbars convert to touch
>     menus and buttons become larger. You can hide all the menus and
>     toolbars to get the most out of your screen and we use HTML5
>     capabilities to enable you to get the most out of your browser. Smart
>     bookmarks allow you to quickly continue where you left off.
> - Community-driven and Open: MindMup is free, opensource, without any marketing, ads or spam. We built the software for ourselves and we
>     respect our users. Freemind mindmap import/export allows users to
>     easily take maps in and out. Development is user-driven, and we work
>     on the features our users vote for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is [link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/FreeMind.shtml) to download freemind to create Mind maps.